# Very simple android-php communication does not work with http post

Tags: php, android, string, post, client-server

I have a really simple code that does not work. I just want to send a string from an android app to a php server. Nothing fancy. I looked for similar questions but i didn't come up with anything.
I don't get the problem, the logcat does not give any error and everything seems working fine, but when i run my php script and send the string it does not happen anything.

this is my app's code

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("your_string", yourString));

try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(""); //my correct script adress
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));           
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); 
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Succesfully uploaded!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and this is php server

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['your_string']) && $_POST['your_string'] != '') {
        $your_string = $_POST['your_string'];
        echo 'received the string: ' . $your_string;
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you using an accompanying form with this? I can't help with the Android code, but PHP most probably.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried but what is the point of a form?

Comment: I usually am under the impression that a POST variable is used in conjunction with a form. I'm not that Android-savvy when it comes to code like that. I take it that your Android code is mimicking it?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, it should be like a form that send a POST variable

Comment: Usually, in PHP with POST variables, the form would contain and resemble something like `<form method="post" action="xxx"><input type="text" name="your_string">` to work in conjunction with `$_POST['your_string']` - Your conditional statement is looking for that.

Comment: Try using the URL that you have in `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("");` in your android browser and see if it works in browser. Maybe your php server is not accessible from you android phone.

Comment: i have already did this, it works fine! @ksarmalkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running your android code async? Consider using an [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Also be sure to add the Content type header:

```
HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
httppost.addHeader(entity.getContentType());
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

You may also check the server response and log it so you know where's your problem, like this:

```
Log.d("Res",EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
```

Wish you luck ;)

Comment: perfect, i'll try to follow these advices, thank you

Comment: i've tried 'Log.d("Res",EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));' and it gives me "received the string" ! @couceirof